# Raspberry Pi 3 , OpenCV and Picamera

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi3

Is there a way for opencv function of `cv2.VideoCapture()` to work with raspiCam. I currently own a raspberry pi 3 model B and it has opencv version 2.4.9.1 installed on it. I did recently come across a post on stack overflow that mentioned that `cv2.VideoCapture()` only works for USB plugged in cameras but is it possible for it work with `raspiCam(Camera Module V2)`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `picamera`.

Check out [this guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/), it should do the trick. You can probably skip the virtualenv stuff but it's good practice.